# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name})

Tags: reactjs

I have this exception:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
> object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of
> children, use an array instead. in h1 (created by Contact) in Contact
> (created by App) in div (created by App) in App
> (/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42)

what am i doing wrong?

````
import React from "react"



export default function Contact(name){
    return <h1>hi {name}!</h1>
}

-------------------------------------------
import React from "react"
import Contact from "./Contact.js"

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="contacts">
          <Contact("Ed")/>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default App

-------------------------------------
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import App from "./App"

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))```
````

Answer (score 1):

We should not call the component function by ourselves [A good e.g shown here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component),

Instead you should pass data as `props` [Read more about props in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

`<Component prop1 = "value1" prop2 = value2 ... />`

In your case it should be something as

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="contacts">
          <Contact name="Ed"/>  // now `name` is available in `props` object          
        </div>
    )
}
```

To make use of it you can either use as `props.name` or destructure it  as`{name}` like below

```
export default function Contact(props){
    return <h1>hi {props.name}!</h1>
}
```

or

```
export default function Contact({name}){
    return <h1>hi {name}!</h1>
}
```